# How to invalidate CloudFront cache of dynamic content when content is updated

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I am developing Web APIs using AWS Lambda, API Gateway and CloudFront.
CloudFront is currently used as reverse proxy to some endpoints of API Gateway, cache behaviors are disabled at all.

There are several frequently-used APIs, of which contents are **rarely-updated (e.g. once a week or once a month)**, therefore are candidates for caching for faster response time.

However, I am wondering how to invalidate such CloudFront cache of **frequently-used-but-rarely-updated** dynamic content when their contents are updated.
My observation is that CloudFront holds cache of older content, since CloudFront does not pass requests to API origin, until cache reaches max-age.

E.g.: Let's say I have a `GET /projects/PROJECT_ID/members` API.
Project members are rarely updated, but once member added/removed via `PUT /projects/PROJECT_ID/members` API, cache should be invalidated to deliver the freshly-updated content of project members.

Should I invalidate the very-particular URL (`/projects/ABC/members` for above example) using [invalidation API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) each time after updating their content (`PUT /projects/ABC/members` invoked) ?
Or, should I avoid to cache such dynamic content?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1-Call the invalidation API each time someone edits your member list.
For example, if someone adds/remove/edit member list (not get request), you should call invalidation API in Cloudfront and invalidate the path

/projects/PROJECT_ID/members

2-Control cache on your API side, also you can set header for some resources to cache in Cloudfront for sometimes.

For more info about CloudFront invalidation API, check the following link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateInvalidation.html

Comment: Thanks.Could you add more detail what types of HTTP header can be used tocontrol cache behavior for dynamic content on the above example?

Comment: You can use max-age and  Cache-Control header, for more detail read the following document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Comment: If I understanding correctly, CloudFront does not invalidate cache until cache reached its max-age specified by origin via such HTTP headers.  I would like to know how to force CloudFront invalidate cache via HTTP headers, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle this:

1. CloudFront Cache Invalidation.
   If you are using S3 as origin, then you can create an S3 event on lambda function. This lambda will automatically invalidate CloudFront cache if there is a change in S3.
2. Use cache headers like Min. TTL, Max. TTL or Default TTL to define how much time you want those objects in cache before CloudFront makes a call to origin.
3. Use object versioning on you object. So, that CloudFront will fetch latest version of the objects everytime.

Can refer CloudFront docs for more information on these.